# Using Docker volumes for accessing data in another directory is leading to

Tags: docker, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

I have a project that I'm running that looks like this:

```
root
   \-- data
          \-- train.csv
          \-- images
                   \-- img1.png ... img10000.png
   \-- project
             \-- scripts
                       \-- run.sh
             \-- main.py
             \-- Dockerfile
```

From the directory `project` I usually do `bash ./scripts/run.sh` and within `run.sh` I have `python ./main.py --data_file /data/train.csv --img_dir /data/images`. For some context, this is a machine learning project that deals with images.

The Docker file that I have looks like this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y python3.10 python3-pip

RUN pip3 install --upgrade requests poetry
RUN ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-root

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/app/scripts/run.sh"]
```

When I try to run this, I get the error that the program can't find `train.csv`. I learned that I can use things called volumes in order to handle this, and so I added a  `VOLUME /data` line inside my Docker file, built it, then ran the command `docker -v /data:/data -it docker_image` but am still getting the error that the path doesn't exist.

What is the problem? I'm assuming that I'm not properly using volumes, but am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What is the current directory when you start your Docker container?

Comment: Is you host `data` is under the root of file system? And what if if you ssh into the container and watch the required folder manually?

Comment: @Jib. Current directory is `project`. The data that I'm using is stored in a NAS so I'm accessing it that way.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Yes, my data is under root. I unfortunately don't know what you mean by SSH into the container... :(

Comment: Can you provide the output of `docker run --rm [image_name] find /app`? And also the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Docker cannot find the host directory to be mounted. According to your comment, the right command should be: `docker -v abspath/to/project/data:/data -it docker_image` or `docker -v ../data:/data -it docker_image`.

As a personal preference I use absolute paths for fixed and known location in order to avoid relative paths issues..

A nice way to investigate is to get into your running container and inspect what is wrong with the `docker exec` command. There you can verify the directory content, etc.